# App URL Scheme not getting registered

Tags: ios, redirect, url-scheme

I have created an App URL Scheme in my `Info.plist` so that I can handle an oauth redirect.

```
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
        <array>
            <string>Lifestream</string>
        </array>
        <key>CFBundleURLName</key>
        <string>com.sullinger.lifestream.callback</string>
    </dict>
</array>
```

When I deploy the app to the simulator or my device, then close the app, open Safari and type in `Lifestream://com.sullinger.lifestream.callback`, Safari tells me it can't find the web page. Am I missing a step in getting a URL scheme registered with the OS?

Comment: Did you manually edit the Info.plist or did you enter the values through the Info tab of your target in Xcode?

Comment: I edited the info.plist by following [this example](http://iosdevelopertips.com/cocoa/launching-your-own-application-via-a-custom-url-scheme.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use with:

```
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleURLName</key>
            <string>com.sullinger.lifestream.callback</string>
            <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
            <array>
                <string>callback</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </array>
```

In App Delegate:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url {
    NSLog(@"url recieved: %@", url);
    NSLog(@"query string: %@", [url query]);
    NSLog(@"host: %@", [url host]);
    NSLog(@"url path: %@", [url path]);
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: How would I navigate to that, I'm not sure what the URL entered into Safari would look like

Comment: For example that my url scheme: `callback://login?user=abcxyz&?token=1ac3ewrffs`

Comment: How is this answer any different from what the OP is already doing (other than using a different scheme)?